# How to modify .htaccess so that it points to a sub-folder in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Codeinginter provide .htaccess file as explained below. It is from [CI User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html).

However when I add this file in xampp/htdocs/mycodeigniter, and point to http://127.0.0.1/mycodeigniter/somepage, it goes to http://127.0.0.1/xampp which is the root file in htdocs.

How can I fix the file so that it points to http://127.0.0.1/mycodeigniter/somepage?

++++++++++++

By default, the index.php file will be included in your URLs:
example.com/index.php/news/article/my_article

You can easily remove this file by using a .htaccess file with some simple rules. Here is an example of such a file, using the "negative" method in which everything is redirected except the specified items:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

In the above example, any HTTP request other than those for index.php, images, and robots.txt is treated as a request for your index.php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a relative substitution path:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may as well want to exclude the css and javascripts files from the redirection

Replace this : RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|robots.txt)
With this : RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|robots.txt|stylesheets|javascript)