# Codeigniter within directory htaccess 

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter project `light` inside the folder `projects`, it looks like this `site.com/projects/light`. For some reason the standard `.htaccess` will not route all calls to `index.php`. What needs to be changed or added?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify .htaccess so that it points to a sub-folder in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484306/how-to-modify-htaccess-so-that-it-points-to-a-sub-folder-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `RewriteRule` is redirecting to /index.php, rather than /projects/light/index.php.